# Converting zero integer to zero float implicity

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, llvm-clang

For months, I've had a project that uses this basic struct:

```
  struct screenPoint {
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    screenPoint(float x_, float y_): x{x_}, y{y_}{}
  };
```

Everything was fine, and then upgraded to Xcode 8 which presumably compiles C++ a bit differently. After hours of debugging, I discovered that code I've used that looks like this:

```
screenPoint offset{0,0}; //undefined behavior?
```

No longer guaranteed that the members would be 0. Often one or both of them was approx 2E20. I finally fixed the issue by doing this:

```
  screenPoint offset{0.0f,0.0f}; //works, the members are zeroed out
```

Is there a change in C++ that no longer converts integers to floats as I'd been expecting?

Attempting to reproduce this on the Mac or the iOS Simulator in Xcode, I cannot. However, the following basic test running on a 4-year old iPad reveals that the case of `{0,0}` does not make the floats equal to exactly zero in random cases:

```
struct screenPoint {
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    screenPoint(float x_, float y_): x{x_}, y{y_}{}
};

class foo{
public:
    foo(int x){}
private:
    screenPoint s{0,0};
};


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    while (1) {
        foo f(1); //see comment below
    } nib.
}
```

Placing a breakpoint on the line `foo f(1)` shows that the value of member `s` is not always 0 and 0 for x and y.

I combined the C++ into the Objective C file for convenience of this example, but in my code it is a separate C++ static library.

Comment: Are you using the default Apple LLVM compiler?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes

Comment: I have a very hard time believing that a compiler will stick anything other than 0, into both `float`s.

Comment: That must be an implementation bug. But it would be good to see a [mcve].

Comment: @juanchopanza i've added code that reproduces the problem on an iPad. I cannot reproduce on other architectures.

Comment: Does the `foo` constructor touch member variable `s` in any way at all? In your *actual* code I mean?

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's possible in Objective-C (or Objective-C++) but could you try to initialize the `foo` object with curly bracers instead? I.e. do `foo f{1}`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the foo constructor does not touch `s` and curly brace initialization makes no difference.

Comment: Declare screenPoint x and y members as 'const' to ensure they are not touched.